# Не видит классы после сборки(selenium)

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, jar

Написал программу, собираю в исполняемый jar-файл. Не запускается:не видит классы
Содержимое pom.xml: `
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>SteamRegger</groupId>
<artifactId>SteamRegger</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium.client-drivers</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java-client-driver</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

`

[image: вывод консоли]

Comment: У тебя билд делаеться без зависимостей. Смотри сюда http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven

Comment: Да, помогло, спасибо. Все решилось добавлением еще одного плагина на зависимости.